# Add self-closing shortcode button to TinyMCE in WP 4.6

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, tinymce

I'm familiar with creating self-closing shortcodes like:

```
// shortcode
function wpse_shortcode_example( $wpse_atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $wpse_atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'width' => '100%',
            'height' => 'auto',
        ),
        $wpse_atts,
        'wpse'
    );

    // Return
    return '<embed 
             src="' . $wpse_atts['src'] . '"
             width="' . $wpse_atts['width'] . '"
             height="' . $wpse_atts['height'] . '";

}
add_shortcode( 'wpse', 'wpse_shortcode_example' );
```

but I would like to start adding these to the TinyMCE.  I've done several searches but all of the search results are either dated or use an approach that is no longer recommended:

- [How to add a shortcode button to the TinyMCE editor?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72394/how-to-add-a-shortcode-button-to-the-tinymce-editor): excellent starting point but the question was created in 2012.
- [WordPress Shortcodes: A Complete Guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/): good article but from 2012 and it uses `query_posts()` but could be tweaked
- [Guide to Creating Your Own WordPress Editor Buttons](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons--wp-30182): is a nice article but still from awhile ago, 2013, but it doesn't cover the basics or foundation to use TinyMCE.

I know Developer is still in it's early stages but the Plugin Handbook only briefly talks about [TinyMCE Enhanced Shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/tinymce-enhanced-shortcodes/) and [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and [`add_shortcode()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) don't mention TinyMCE.

So this leads me to my question.  What is the basic procedure for turning a 
self-closing shortcode into a clickable button in the TinyMCE editor?

Comment: So you mean how to create a button in the TinyMCE editor that injects a self-closing shortcode into the content?

Comment: @birgire Yes I would like to know the foundation for integrating a custom button into TinyMCE that will add the shortcode to the post visual.

Comment: Did you check out the great [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139164/26350) by @bueltge ?

Comment: @birgire no it didn't return from my searching but it's a good Q&A

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We start by adding the custom TinyMCE Button:

```
function add_mce_button_custom_em() {
    // check user permissions
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
    if ( 'true' == get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_tinymce_plugin_custom_em' );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_mce_button_custom_em' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'add_mce_button_custom_em');
```

Then we declare and register the new button:

```
// Declare script for new button
function add_tinymce_plugin_custom_em( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['custom_em'] = get_template_directory_uri() .'/plug/custom-em/custom-em.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

// Register new button in the editor
function register_mce_button_custom_em( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'custom_em' );
    return $buttons;
}
```

Finally, we decide which buttons (more on buttons can be found at [Content Formatting](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/)) we want to display. Obviously, if you have UX in mind, you would only display a few of them, example:

```
// TinyMCE: TinyMCE choose which buttons you want to display
function myformatTinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'styleselect,bold,custom_em,blockquote,hr,aligncenter,link,unlink,spellchecker,undo,removeformat';
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

As you can see in the `add_tinymce_plugin_custom_em` function, we are declaring a javascript file inside `get_template_directory_uri() .'/plug/custom-em/custom-em.js'`

So create the `custom-em.js` file, and then you have two ways to go about this.

Either you can go with the following shortcode format `[shortcode foo="" bar=""]` or `[shortcode][/shortcode]`.

Let's start with the `[shortcode foo="" bar=""]` format:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.custom_em', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('custom_em', {
                title : 'Custom EM',
                image : url+'/images/btn_custom_em.png',
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand(
                        "mceInsertContent",
                        false,
                        "[shortcode foo=\"\" bar=\"\"]"
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('custom_em', tinymce.plugins.custom_em);
})();
```

As you can see, we use an image as the button icon. You can change that into text as outlined in the example below.

The following is what we use on our own platform, it wraps the selection into: `<em class="whatever">hello world</em>`:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('custom_em', function( editor, url ) {

        editor.on('init', function(e) {
            this.formatter.register('thetarget', {
                inline : 'em',
                classes : 'whatever'
            });
        });

        editor.addButton('custom_em', {
            text: 'Custom EM',
            icon: false,
            onclick : function() {
                var contents = editor.selection.getContent(),
                tags = jQuery(jQuery.parseHTML(contents)).find('em.whatever').andSelf();
                editor.formatter.toggle('thetarget');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Please post results and perform edits. TinyMCE is a plague and requires headache but can be solves in a collaborative manner.